# Skewness in robust regression

Tags: r, regression, robust, skewness

I am doing a robust regression to predicted a left-skewed outcome.  Do I still need to do a transform on my data before doing robust regression, or will that issue be taken care of by the robust method? If so, what transform would you recommend? When I plot my residuals after doing robust regression, they still look left-skewed.

I tried doing a transform ($\text{predicted.value}^4$) but even then my residuals are still left-skewed. I'm worried I'm not meeting certain assumptions of robust regression, but I'm not sure since I'm new to this method.

Comment: Can you please specify which kind of "robust" regression you are using?

Comment: Yes I have just been using rlm() in R

Comment: How would transforming *predicted values* have any effect on the regression? Surely it's an output, not an input.

Comment: The transform was needed so the data fit a linear model

Comment: There is no reason why a boxcox transform could not be used with robust regression. But without more details not much more can be said.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems impossible to transform the predicted values, as they are output. This was raised in a comment, but not responded to.